# Why all the columns in this bootstrap example are stacked?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This code is from w3schools.com examples:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    .col-sm-8
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">.col-sm-6</div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">.col-sm-6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div>
</div>
```

Example page: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_grid_ex4
Why all the columns are stacked on each other. It is rendering like this:

8
6
6
4

It should render like this as per my understanding:

--------|----|
8          4
----|----
6      6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should work fine. The columns will stack on screen widths less than 992px. If you want the columns to never stack, you would use the `col-xs-*` classes..

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    .col-xs-8
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">.col-xs-4</div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/oYL80uQpSY

Comment: Damn, just changed yours to include the xs whilst I posted. This is correct.

Comment: OP is just curious that how is that producing the result like?

Comment: Because bootstrap now uses a mobile first approach to CSS, if you do not specify the smallest unit it will simply use its default (which is 12), taking up the whole row's width. You must specify the col-xs-* if you want control from smallest unit all the way up.

Answer (score 0):

Col-sm are for small devices, try using col-md-x

Comment: This would make the OP's problem worse, making them stack all the way up to the md size, then making them stack how he wants. it is the col-xs-* that he needs

Answer (score 0):

You're not opening your browser window to a wide enough size. The render window doesn't match the "sm" media query.

Answer (score 0):

They are 12-grid systems of bootstrap.

In your code col-sm-8 is 8-grid layout and col-sm-6 is 6 grid layout.

So, you have 8-grid layout and within this 6-grid layout are maintained but since there can only be 8-grid layout but combining 6-grid + 6-grid would be 12-grid layout and which is never gonna occupy within the 8-grid layout and this is why col-md-6 goes below and produces the result what you see.

Comment: Sorry for my english that I could not make you clear, I think.

Answer (score 0):

your code works fine, you just have to try it at the correct screen size, you can always add more classes to adjust to screen sizes like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
    .col-sm-8
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">.col-sm-6</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">.col-sm-6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">.col-sm-4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to do this, you can just use col-xs-* as bootstrap now uses the mobile first approach. This will simply clutter the mark-up with unnecessary classes

Comment: this if you want them to stack on small devices and then expand on one raw on larger ones, but not if you want to specify it statically across all right?

Comment: yeah sure, if you want the col's to be different sizes later on you can specify that at the size you want with a different value. But as you are using the same col size for all sizes (in your example, 6) you simply need to specify the smallest. So if you want it to be 6 up to `lg` when it then needs to be 4 you would do `<div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">content</div>`